# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule: custom post type links with subdomain

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a custom post type and for this custom post type i have the sigle page like this 
http://example.com/?custom_post=titlehere

How can i rewrite this url ( with add_rewrite_rule ) into a link like

http://titlehere.example.com

So far i have this code

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^http://[\w.-]+\.example.com?', 'custom_post=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Did i write the regex wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you look at [This Demo](http://regexr.com/3d3a2), you can see that `//` is underlined. This is because they have not been escaped. They should be selected like this, `\/\/`.

Here is the RegEx you should be using:

```
^http:\/\/[\w.-]+\.example.com?
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/3d3a5)</kbd>

Also, I am not sure if you wanted to select the `?`, since currently it makes the `m` in `com` optional, but if you did you need to escape it like so, `\?`. However, this will select http://foo.example.com?something, if you want to select http://foo.example.com/?something, use the following RegEx:

```
^http:\/\/[\w.-]+\.example.com\/\?
```

---

Note that using the any RegEx I specified above may still not work. `$matches[1]` selects the first match in the RegEx, however you have no capturing groups. I would suggest using the following full code:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^http:\/\/([\w.-]+)\.example.com\/?', 'custom_post=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is still not working : the code is  add_rewrite_rule('^http:\/\/[\w.-]+\.example.com?/g', 'custom_post=$matches[1]', 'top');

Comment: @user1548981 See my edit, you forgot to include a capturing group, so `$matches[1]` **does not exist!**

Comment: Thanks again. Still not working but i don;t think the regex is to blame this time. I see here http://regexr.com/3d3an that the match is found.  The code is   add_rewrite_rule('^http:\/\/([\w.-]+)\.example.com\/?', 'custom_post=$matches[1]', 'top');

Comment: @user1548981 Try `$matches[0]` and see...? Also, what is happening, is it not redirecting, redirecting to the wrong place, throwing an error?

Comment: Tried with $matches[0] and $matches[2] - still not working

Comment: @user1548981 How is it not working? What is happening, what errors are you getting?

Comment: On http://testme.supermedic.ro  i get a not found, i should get this http://supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=testme , the rule is  add_rewrite_rule('^http:\/\/([\w.-]+)\.supermedic.ro\/?', 'estate_agent=$matches[0]', 'top');

Comment: @user1548981 Okay, you get a 404 Not Found, but what is the URL? Also, please enclose your code in comments with `\``

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand the question "but what is the URL?".  I want to rewrite http://supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=testme into  http://testme.supermedic.ro

Comment: Yes, but when you use my code, and get the 404 Not Found, there will be a website address in the URL bar. Like currently there is `stackoverflow.com/......` in the URL bar, when you use my code what is in the URL bar

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm wasting your time but i still don't get it.  I put the permalink on plain , save the structure again to make sure the rules are flushed. The i check  supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=testme and see it's working, then i type in the address bar testme.supermedic.ro and that gives me the http://testme.supermedic.ro/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi not found page. The link generated by get_permalink() is still in the plain format. Thank you

Comment: @user1548981 Okay that is the information I wanted (don't worry, you have not wasted my time, `;)`). Some servers do not change the URL when there is a 404, so we may have been able to see what was going on (i.e. the new URL)

Comment: @user1548981 Can you try replacing `custom_post=$matches[1]` with `supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=$matches[1]`? Maybe it was redirecting to `testme.supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=.....` instead of just `supermedic.ro/?.....`

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule('^http:\/\/([\w.-]+)\.supermedic.ro\/?', 'http://supermedic.ro/?estate_agent=$matches[1]', 'top');` - no luck

Comment: I also var_dump the global $wp_rewrite in the footer - and from what i see the rule is in place. Maybe i should look at the server level...

Comment: I have done a tail-f on apache logs and i noticed that there is no activity when i call testme.supermedic.ro - which means i should probably look at the dns/ server setup